# Are Soft Bad Sectors recorded in a drive's S.M.A.R.T. data?

Tags: smart, bad-sectors

Yesterday I was faced with a soft bad sector when I decided to run chkdsk.exe in Windows all by myself. I have suspicions that it was caused by a recent Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver update. I wasn't able to take a look at the drive's SMART data when it happened because I immediately decided to do a zero-fill format on it thinking that chkdsk utility won't just cut on fixing it.

After the relatively long zero-fill format process, I decided to reinstall Windows, immediately check its SMART status through CrystalDiskInfo and decided to do a surface scan on HD Tune Pro which fortunately, returned a result that there are no damages on the drive.

Does S.M.A.R.T. consider a soft bad sector as an "actual bad sector"? If the soft bad sectors are fixed, do they reflect in the drive's S.M.A.R.T. data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of time to spend diagnosing problems =P

OK Ariel here's the verdict,

Soft Bad sectors are discovered when the error checking Algorithm of the Operating System finds data doesn't match up with the formatting index of the drive. like a MD5 hash check.

There is a high chance that the software side, i.e. drivers, bugs. Is to blame for this soft bad sector. Therefore S.M.A.R.T values would not have shown problems.

What is S.M.A.R.T? It's a HDD Hardware health "GUESSING" algorithm that factors in variables:

- response time of the HDD,
- Operating Temp,
- Total Time in service,
- manufacturing durability constant (Math here),
- number of major HARD errors, each with respective impacts on the algorithm (cyclic redundancy error).

This basically lets lucky users know when their HDD is most probably gonna fail.

IT CAN RETURN FALSE POSITIVES OR MISS IMPENDING FAILURE.

Predicting when a HDD is gonna fail is like predicting when the mission to mars is going to be.

**Answer:**

I can say with some degree of certainty that **your HDD is fine**. IF you meet this criteria:

- less than 3 year old HDD (HDD ONLY NOT SSD)
- you haven't been tinkering with low level commands or opened it.
- It hasn't been subjected it to harsh conditions

Sources:

http://www.howtogeek.com/173463/bad-sectors-explained-why-hard-drives-get-bad-sectors-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.

http://www.extremetech.com/computing/170748-how-long-do-hard-drives-actually-live-for

Cherrio! You didn't need to zero-fill format. 99.70% says that was useless because chdsk fixes those errors easily. Let alone reinstall windows.